# Conversion from time Duration to time String

Tags: java, android, json, java-time, datetimeformatter

I am getting time through JSON in this format `"DocTime": "PT18H30M"`.

How to convert from this format to normal String time e.g. `"6:30 pm"` in android?

For time being I found this Solution:

```
    String  json = "PT18H30M";
    System.out.println("Server Time: " +json);
    int h = json.indexOf("H");
    int m = json.indexOf("M");
    int hrs = Integer.valueOf(json.substring(2 , h));
   // System.out.println("hrs: " + hrs);
    int min = Integer.valueOf(json.substring((h+1) , m));
   // System.out.println("min: " + min);
    String shrs = (hrs>12)? String.valueOf((hrs - 12)) : String.valueOf(hrs);
    String mode = (hrs>12)? "pm" : "am";
    
    String fTime = shrs+":"+min+" "+mode;
           
    System.out.println("Normal Time: " +fTime);
```

Comment: Your [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) string, `PT18H30M`, says that this is a duration, an amount of time. Are you sure it means 6:30 PM? If so, educate the publisher of the string to omit the `P` for *period* and use either `18:30` or `T18:30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

**With Java-8:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.parse("PT18H30M");
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of((int) duration.toHours(), (int) (duration.toMinutes() % 60));
        System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6:30 pm
```

If your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**With Java-9:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.parse("PT18H30M");
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart());
        System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m a")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6:30 pm
```

Note that [`Duration#toHoursPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toHoursPart--) and [`Duration#toMinutesPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutesPart--) were introduced with Java-9.

Comment: Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.time.Duration#parse  showing this

Comment: @JoydeepSaha That’s where you need the link to *Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring* given in the answer (an alternative is [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)).

Answer (score 2):

### java.time either through desugaring or through ThreeTenABP

It seems that you have received a string where someone has misunderstood the ISO 8601 standard and given you a string representing a duration where they intended a time of day.

I recommened you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work. The problem with the incorrect string can be solved by regarding it as a duration since 00:00.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String docTimeString = "PT18H30M";
    
    Duration docTimeDur = Duration.parse(docTimeString);
    LocalTime docTimeOfDay = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(docTimeDur);
    String humanReadableDocTime = docTimeOfDay.format(formatter);
    
    System.out.println(humanReadableDocTime);
```

Output:

> 6:30 PM

I am exploiting the fact that `Duration.parse()` expects and parses ISO 8601 format.

### "Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.time.Duration#parse" showing this

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: "Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): java.time.Duration#parse" showing this

Comment: @JoydeepSaha I have addressed that already in the answer. Please read that section too.